# Need a buck circuit to go from 48V down to 12V-9V less than 30mA (or half the supply input for a regulator)

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, buck

I need a circuit to go from 48V down to 12V-9V less than 30mA, it doesn't *need* to be a buck converter. I don't want to use transformers as simplicity is good (and adding components to the library is bad) and I probably already have inductors that I could use on my shelf. Most of the stuff out there in IC's only goes up to 36V on bucks or regulators.

How do I make a circuit to do as I described?

Points for being more than 60% efficient as I don't want to burn up 60% of my power on regulation.

Comment: A train of diodes.

Comment: Is there a size limit?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Or just one or two Zener diodes.

Comment: You may want to use an isolated converter as the 48V maybe a safety hazard.
It is pretty easy to find an isolated converter for that.

Comment: I thought about zeners... but I've never used them to span such a big voltage gap, then there is the issue of droop.

Comment: You wont be getting 60% efficient for anything linear... way to make the existing answers invalid.... :(

Comment: Oh wait, it's laptop2d who's asking! Woaaaaaaw. This is so cool. It's like meeting an actor of some famous TV show. - After the Zener diodes I'd use some decoupling capacitors. What kind of answers are you seeking? Microcontroller solution? random IC solution? Transistors + resistors solution? No op-amps?

Comment: @HarrySvensson if you could I'd like a wireless transfer power solution :) If you've read my profile, I don't work much on the transistor level.

Comment: Let me webbench that for you?

Comment: I was looking for more of a creative solution, and actually I found it! I can use the DC to DC's regs that I normally use but tack on a transistor and get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a rough pre-regulator to halve the supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO9cQn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**ADDITION:**

SInce you added >60% efficiency as a new requirement... you need something switching...

How about one of [these](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5019.pdf)...

[image]

Comment: I might be able to use this but with some other 7805 DC DC regulators I have...

Comment: @laptop2d ok, but you need to figure the wattage on Q1. It may get a tad warm.

Comment: Yeah, I've got some 7805 DC\DC's but they go from 36V down to 9V so this will still work, just swap out the regualtor.

Comment: @laptop2d 7809s go to 9V 7805's are 5V regulators.

Comment: not the DC DC converters! Some companies like CUI call some of their models 7805-X, where X is the voltage, super weird...

Comment: @laptop2d oic... well duh... must be to fool the submarines.

Answer (score 3):

**Quick & dirty** HV regulator: everyone has a TL431 stashed somewhere, right?

[image]

I just pulled this one off the net, so you'll need to adjust resistor values. It is not short circuit protected, unless you count Rb limiting the current via pass transistor hFe. It will be stable with output capacitors depending on ESR, can be confirmed via a quick sim with TL431 model. I'd use a general purpose aluminium cap like 100µF on the output. Transient response can be made faster with a cap in parallel with the upper feedback resistor.

**If you want a switcher**, look into the ones designed for Telecom 48V standard, or Power Over Ethernet. For example at [LT](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Internal_Power_Switch_Buck#!1646_Buck!1032_%3C=40!1033_%3E=48!1105_%3C=12!1034_%3E=12!1107_0.05:1.13!vinmin_40!vinmax_48!vout_12!iout_.05!vout2_!iout2_!vout3_!iout3_). I remember seeing lots of such chips on DigiKey when I did a search a while ago, there are some with integrated switch in small packages.

[example](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/allegro-microsystems-llc/A8498SLJTR-T/620-1160-1-ND/1121721)

[example](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54062.pdf)

**If you have a 36V input switcher** then dropping the input voltage with a bunch of diodes or a zener to 30V then running the switcher from that should give you the 60% you want...

Answer (score 2):

With a new spec for 60% efficiency and a voltage ratio of 12/(12+48) =20% for any linear design it is impossible to meet this with a linear design.
Your spec could be defined some other way.

You could use a small SMT transformer, a bipolar input clock and rectifier output **without using a SMPS design**. Also this may cost more than a SMPS.

### Suggestion

[image]

This design took 1 minute and may be exported into 5 standard S/W packages.