# 32v to 12v regulator

Tags: led, voltage-regulator

I am trying to light up 12V LED from 32V comes from another board. I have used voltage regulator (LM7812), but the problem is the regulator heats up very quickly even when I use 12V as input rather than 32! 
Is there any special type of regulators that fit my application?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. A switching regulator.

Comment: lm2576 is a easy to use regulator. You can also buy premade modules of these cheaper than you can make them

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using a [DC to DC drop in replacement](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-supplies-board-mount/922?ColumnSort=573&FV=ffe0039a&page=1&pageSize=500&quantity=&s=N4IgTCBcDaIG4HYAcAGArCAugXyA) like the V7805 or in your case V7812. There is no heat because the DC to DC regulator is efficient and does not regulate the voltage by dissipating power.

Another way is to put a [transistor in series](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342861/need-a-buck-circuit-to-go-from-48v-down-to-12v-9v-less-than-30ma-or-half-the-su) with the regulator if you don't have a current limit